# Getting specific node values of xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

For the below xml , how do i get the the specific values using javascript. For ex : Value of num-chords in D3410

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <product-info>
  <!--  II and III -->
  <D3410 desc="xx" product-type="Gas" num-chords="1" flow-profile-corr="true" diag-func-end-ver="624" reg-def="D3410.xml" /> 
</model-info>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");



 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
  {
```

document.write(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);  document.write("
");  }

Comment: Hi Yogi , It is a not on the browser . It is on my system. I am using testcomplete

Comment: http://blog.dimaj.net/2011/02/howto-read-script-configuration-data-from-xml-in-testcomplete-using-jscript

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
var xml = loadXMLDoc("yourXMLfile.xml");

var val = xml.getElementsByTagName('D3410');

var y = val[0].getAttribute('num-chords');

console.log(y);
```

Comment: No it is not working. It is for desktop bases app and not for webbases application